# c# get iterator position in dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, iterator

I have a `Dictionary<string,string>` and I iterate over its KeyValuePairs. But my issue is that I need to stop the iteration at some point and continue the iteration from the same position. My code is as follows.

```
for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    foreach(var pair in dictionary) /* continue from iterators last position */
    {
          /* do something */
          if(consdition) break;
     }
 }
```

The code is not very clear but I hope my what I'm trying to do is. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could abandon `foreach` and work on the `IEnumerator<T>` directly.

```
using (IEnumerator<<KeyValuePair<K,V>> enumerator = dict.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        DoSomething(enumerator.Current);
        if (condition)
            break;
    }

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        DoMoreWork(enumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

But you might consider refactoring the code so that `foreach` is the outer loop. That's probably easier and cleaner.

```
int i=0;
foreach(var pair in dictionary)
{
      if(condition)
      {
         DoSomething();
         i++;
         if(i<5)
           continue;
         else
           break;
      }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is the only useful suggestion so far.

Comment: Wrapped it in a `using` block so that it is exception-safe. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: The problem with `using` is that it requires the continuation in the same block/method as the first iteration. This is the case in my example, but no idea if it's the case with the OPs code.

Comment: Will not add `-1`, however In `DoMoreWork()` you are not checking `if (condition)`, and if condition is true, **To Fix:** you have to do `DoMoreWorkAgain()` and so on.., you have to wrap the whole code "after the using maybe" in a bigger while or just in the main `for` loop and remove the second `while (enumerator.MoveNext())`...

Comment: I'm not really sure what the OP wants to do. I assume what he wrote is just an example since IMO nesting loops the way he did makes no sense.

Comment: After all we are answering the question depending on the code he posted, So I think `O(n^2)` in the original code right?

Comment: @Jalal: No, the original code is `O(n)` -- what makes you think otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

Try out LINQ to find item index by condition:

```
int index = dictionary.TakeWhile(condition).Count();
```

If you can extract your condition into a Func you can reuse it in SkipWhile() as well:

```
Func<int, bool> condition = (key) => { return key == "textToSearch"; };
int index = dictionary.TakeWhile(item => condition(item.Key)).Count();

// use inverted condition
var secondPart = dictionary.SkipWhile(item => !condition(item.Key));
```

PS: if performance is matter it won't be the best solution

Comment: "...and continue the iteration from the same position". Your solution certainly works for stopping. =)

Comment: @J. Steen: Yep, exactly as I said "to find item index by condition". I will consider post my siolution bit later

Comment: Hmm. Yes, I see now. Not immediately obvious, since I was distracted by the whole TakeWhile to re-iterate over the collection... =)

Comment: @J. Steen: anyway you are right, such suggestions is not an answer

Answer (score 1):

Look into the term yield

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Switch the `foreach` to `for` loop and declare the index of the loop outside the loops, like:

```
int pairIndex = 0;
for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    for (; pairIndex < dictionary.Count; pairIndex++)
    {
          KeyValuePair<string, string> pair = dictionary.ElementAt(pairIndex);
          /* do something */
          if(consdition) break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: @Anonymous Downvoter: the `O(n^2)` is in the code that was posted by the OP`I need to stop the iteration at some point and continue the iteration from the same position. My code is as follows.`...., this answer is just answering his question  depending on the code posted

Comment: The `for` loop is `O(n)` and `ElementAt` is `O(n)`, so nesting them yields `O(n^2)`. Since the OP just had the outer loop, the original solution is `O(n)`.